# Is there a way to tell if a Lenovo Laptop configuraton from the Serial Number?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, serial-number, lenovo-desktop-computer

Browsing the listings of older model or used computers, many of them don't list the specific options they shipped with. Is there a way I can find this out from Lenovo or with a tool or utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

If you take the Serial Number and go to the [Parts Lookup webpage (used for ordering new parts)](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/partslookup) you can look up the machine. It will show you what parts it shipped it by default, or if it had an optional part like a backlit keyboard. `R9ZK7L0` is an example of a Lenovo Part Number for a laptop that shipped with a backlit keyboard.